# global.Exp.Data.getLocalDataSet() empty on refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, azure

The first method is used to get the record from the database and fill the data to the grid. The second method is used to view the user details. When the user clicks the second method it will return the value and show the user the details. But refreshing the page in user detail that time

```
 var local = global.Exp.Data.getLocalDataSet("UserInfoTenant/ListUsers")
```

doesn't have the value.

The error message: `Error: Unable to get property 'FirstName' of undefined or null reference.`

---

```
function loadUserInfo(extension, renderArea) 
{
    global.UserInfoTenantExtension.isUserInfoTabNavigating = null;
    global.UserInfoTenantExtension.UserInfotabRenderArea = renderArea;
    global.Shell.UI.Spinner.show();
    **global.Exp.Data.getData**({
        url: ListUsers, //controller "ActionName" name
        dataSetName: ListUsers,
        forceCacheRefresh: true
    }).done(function (url, dataSet) {
        var grid,
        columns = [
        {
            name: "Id", field: "Id", filterable: true, sortable: true, type: "navigation", navigationField: "Id" 
        },
        { name: "First Name", field: "FirstName" },
        { name: "Title", field: "Title" },
        { name: "Comment", field: "Comment" },
        { name: "Is Active", field: "IsDeleted" },
        ];
        grid = renderArea.find(".userInfoContainer") //template html class name 
        .wazObservableGrid("destroy")
        .wazObservableGrid({
        lastSelectedRow: null,
        data: dataSet.data,
        keyField: "Id",
        columns: columns,
        gridOptions: {
            rowSelect: onRowSelected,
            pagerOptions: {
                pageSize: 10
            },
        }
    });
    global.Shell.UI.Spinner.hide();
});
showCommands();}
```

---

```
function loadtab(renderArea, renderData) {
    if (global.UserInfoTenantExtension.UserInfoTab.currentContext) {
        **var local = global.Exp.Data.getLocalDataSet("UserInfoTenant/ListUsers")**
        var filtered = $(local.data).filter(function () {
            return this.FirstName.replace(' ', '_') == global.UserInfoTenantExtension.UserInfoTab.currentContext.current.itemName.replace(' ', '_');
        });
        if (filtered.length > 0)
            global.UserInfoTenantExtension.selectedDoctor = viewModel.selectedUser = filtered[0];
    }
    viewModel.selectedUser = global.UserInfoTenantExtension.selectedDoctor;
    global.UserInfoTenantExtension.templates.DoctorDetails.link($(renderArea), viewModel, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At function loadUserInfo, supply subscription Id of the resource to following:

```
global.Exp.Data.getData({
        url: ListUsers, //controller "ActionName" name
        dataSetName: ListUsers,
        ajaxData: {
                 subscriptionIds: subscriptionRegisteredToService
                 },
        forceCacheRefresh: true
    })
```

once you render the data on the page. next call of `global.Exp.Data.getLocalDataSet("UserInfoTenant/ListUsers")` will bring the data.

if there is not data in first call then try AjaxPost to fetch data.

```
Shell.Net.ajaxPost({
            dataSetName: url,
                url: url,
            data: data
        });
```